# How to make a setup for Visual Studio 2012 project which uses SQL Server CE 4.0 and .net framework 4.0 or 3.5 sp1 with GAC registering?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, gac, sql-server-ce-4, stimulsoft

I have created a Windows forms application project in VS 2012 which uses SQL Server CE 4.0 (Compact Edition) and .NET framework 3.5 sp1 and in future 4.0!

Now I don't know how to create a setup! Because no setup project is supported in VS 2012 except Installshield LE which doesn't support SQL Server CE 4.0 prerequisite!

Also I need to register some DLLs (stimulsoft reporting) into GAC!

I know that if I want to be sure about GAC, I must build a MSI, but I don't know how to include SQL Server CE 4.0!

I have searched all over the Docs in the earth!! please help me :(

Comment: [Have a look at WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'll try it in a few hours...

Comment: Wix not working as i wish :( also it's not simple

Comment: I didn't claim it was simple - but it's free. If you can afford to spend money - look at other MSI installers - you'll find them by searching on Google for "Authoring MSI tools" - plenty of choices!